# how can i search text within the text box in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

The search function i have done is working however it only finds the word once where I need to find all the words that entered in the search for text box

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim Search As String
    Dim Where As Long

   ' Get search string from user.
   Search = InputBox("Enter text to be found:")

   ' Find string in text.
   Where = InStr(TheText.Text, Search)

   If Where <> 0 Then
       TheText.Focus()
       TheText.SelectionStart = Where - 1
       TheText.SelectionLength = Len(Search)
   Else
       MsgBox("String not found.")
   End If

   txtR.Text = CountWords(Search)

   Sorting.Items.Add(txtR.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Text box control doesn't allow multiple selects like that, but the Rich Textbox control does. It would essentially be the same code that you have, but you would need a position number to keep track of the most recent find and loop until there are no more instances of the search string.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the matching items, you can use a Regular Expression. The items that match your criteria would be included in the RegEx.Matches collection. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx#Y527